# Extract labels membership / classification from a cut dendrogram in R (i.e.: a cutree function for dendrogram)

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, dendextend

I'm trying to extract a classification from a dendrogram in R that I've `cut` at a certain height. This is easy to do with `cutree` on an `hclust`object, but I can't figure out how to do it on a `dendrogram` object.

Further, I can't just use my clusters from the original hclust, becuase (frustratingly), the numbering of the classes from `cutree` is different from the numbering of classes with `cut`.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

classification<-cutree(hc,h=70)

dend1 <- as.dendrogram(hc)
dend2 <- cut(dend1, h = 70)


str(dend2$lower[[1]]) #group 1 here is not the same as
classification[classification==1] #group 1 here
```

Is there a way to either get the classifications to map to each other, or alternatively to extract lower branch memberships from the `dendrogram` object (perhaps with some clever use of `dendrapply`?) in a format more like what `cutree` gives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would propose for you to use the `cutree` function from the *[dendextend](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/)* package. It includes a dendrogram method (i.e.: `dendextend:::cutree.dendrogram`).

**You can learn more about the package from [its introductory vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html).**

I should add that while your function (`classify`) is good, there are several advantage for using `cutree` from *dendextend*:

1. It also allows you to use a specific `k` (number of clusters), and not just `h` (a specific height).
2. It is consistent with the result you would get from cutree on hclust (`classify` will not be).
3. It will often be faster.

Here are examples for using the code:

```
# Toy data:
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
dend1 <- as.dendrogram(hc)

# Get the package:
install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)

# Get the package:
cutree(dend1,h=70) # it now works on a dendrogram
# It is like using:
dendextend:::cutree.dendrogram(dend1,h=70)
```

By the way, on the basis of this function, *dendextend* allows the user to do more cool things, like color branches/labels based on cutting the dendrogram:

```
dend1 <- color_branches(dend1, k = 4)
dend1 <- color_labels(dend1, k = 5)
plot(dend1)
```

[image]

Lastly, here is some more code for demonstrating my other points:

```
# This would also work with k:
cutree(dend1,k=4)

# and would give identical result as cutree on hclust:
identical(cutree(hc,h=70)  , cutree(dend1,h=70)  )
   # TRUE

# But this is not the case for classify:
identical(classify(dend1,70)   , cutree(dend1,h=70)  )
   # FALSE


install.packages("microbenchmark")
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(classify = classify(dend1,70),
               cutree = cutree(dend1,h=70)  )
#    Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
#    classify  9.70135  9.94604 10.25400 10.87552  80.82032   100
#      cutree 37.24264 37.97642 39.23095 43.21233 141.13880   100
# 4 times faster for this tree (it will be more for larger trees)

# Although (if to be exact about it) if I force cutree.dendrogram to not go through hclust (which can happen for "weird" trees), the speed will remain similar:
microbenchmark(classify = classify(dend1,70),
               cutree = cutree(dend1,h=70, try_cutree_hclust = FALSE)  )
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
#    classify  9.683433  9.819776  9.972077 10.48497 29.73285   100
#      cutree 10.275839 10.419181 10.540126 10.66863 16.54034   100
```

If you are thinking of ways to improve this function, please patch it through here:

https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/blob/master/R/cutree.dendrogram.R

I hope you, or others, will find this answer helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and for the development of this wonderful package!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words Oreotrephes. Let me know if you come by any issues, or new features that you think would be helpful. Best, Tal

Comment: Is there a way to extract the group assignments from `color_branches(dend1, k = 4)`?

Comment: I'm interested to in extracting the group assignments from color_branches()

Answer (score 8):

I ended up creating a function to do it using `dendrapply`. It's not elegant, but it works

```
classify <- function(dendrogram,height){

#mini-function to use with dendrapply to return tip labels
 members <- function(n) {
    labels<-c()
    if (is.leaf(n)) {
        a <- attributes(n)
        labels<-c(labels,a$label)
    }
    labels
 }

 dend2 <- cut(dendrogram,height) #the cut dendrogram object
 branchesvector<-c()
 membersvector<-c()

 for(i in 1:length(dend2$lower)){                             #for each lower tree resulting from the cut
  memlist <- unlist(dendrapply(dend2$lower[[i]],members))     #get the tip lables
  branchesvector <- c(branchesvector,rep(i,length(memlist)))  #add the lower tree identifier to a vector
  membersvector <- c(membersvector,memlist)                   #add the tip labels to a vector
 }
out<-as.integer(branchesvector)                               #make the output a list of named integers, to match cut() output
names(out)<-membersvector
out
}
```

Using the function makes it clear that the problem is that cut assigns category names alphabetically while cutree assigns branch names left to right.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
dend1 <- as.dendrogram(hc)

classify(dend1,70) #Florida 1, North Carolina 1, etc.
cutree(hc,h=70)    #Alabama 1, Arizona 1, Arkansas 1, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you make your dendogram, use the cutree method and then convert it to a dataframe.  The following code makes a nice dendrogram using the library dendextend:

```
library(dendextend)

# set the number of clusters
clust_k <- 8

# make the hierarchical clustering
par(mar = c(2.5, 0.5, 1.0, 7))
d <- dist(mat, method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(d)
dend <- d %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram
labels_cex(dend) <- .65
dend %>% 
  color_branches(k=clust_k) %>%
  color_labels() %>%
  highlight_branches_lwd(3) %>% 
  plot(horiz=TRUE, main = "Branch (Distribution) Clusters by Heloc Attributes", axes = T)
```

[image]

Based on the coloring scheme, it looks like the clusters are formed around the threshold of 4.  So to get the assignments into a dataframe, we need to get the clusters and then `unlist()` them.

First you need to get the clusters themselves, however, it is just a single vector of the number, the row names are the actual labels.

```
# creates a single item vector of the clusters    
myclusters <- cutree(dend, k=clust_k, h=4)

# make the dataframe of two columns cluster number and label
clusterDF <-  data.frame(Cluster = as.numeric(unlist(myclusters)),
                         Branch = names(myclusters))

# sort by cluster ascending
clusterDFSort <- clusterDF %>% arrange(Cluster)
```