# I am doing text mining, if I have a dendrogram of some documents, then cut it in one level How can I get all the terms in that level of cut?

Tags: r

I have a code like this:

```
nf<- read.csv("test2.csv")#test 2 is containing 79 rows(name of documents) and one column of text as containing document.
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(nf$segment))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x,"shall"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x,"will"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x,"can"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x,"could"))
corpus  <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument, language = "english") 
td.mat <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus))
dist.mat <- dist(t(as.matrix(td.mat)))

ft <- hclust(dist.mat, method="ward.D2")
plot(ft)
```

[my dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziaPg.jpg)

I have  cluster dendrogram from documents. if I cut I in height=50 .how I can have the terms in this level?

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452472/extract-labels-membership-classification-from-a-cut-dendrogram-in-r-i-e-a-c

Comment: thanks but It gives documents only. I want to gain terms in every level of dendrogram.